# I can't understand the result Why that slash added ? How to remove that?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a problem with below extension.

That extension will converts Any optional Value to String. Like long, Int, Float and optional string.

When I try to convert text like

> "doesn't contain"

optional value it automaticaly added

> \

in the single quote.

I get the result

> doesn\'t contain

```
 extension Optional where Wrapped == AnyObject{
    func toString() -> String{
       if let value = self{
          return "\(value)"
       }

       return ""
     }
 }
```

Here is playGround sample.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

How to remove that "\" in the result.

Comment: The backslash is virtual to escape the single quote in a literal string wrapped in double quotes. And your extension cannot work this way. And please post text, not images.

Comment: I got the backslash in my extension too.

Comment: Everywhere an Optional is printed it's printed literally `Optional("...")` and all special characters within the double quotes are escaped implicitly.

Answer (score -1):

The \ is shown when you call the `description` method on an optional `String`, which is what happens implicitly when you pass the string to `print`.  It is just to clarify that there is a literal ' in the string and that the ' is not a delimiter.

If I use

```
extension Optional {
    func toString() -> String{
       if let value = self{
          return "\(value)"
       }

       return ""
     }
 }

 let x: String? = "doesn't contain"
 print(x.toString())
```

it gives me

> doesn't contain

without a \

I would probably code this as a computed variable

```
extension Optional {    
    var stringValue: String {
        return self != nil ? "\(self!)" : ""
    }
}
```